Unable to load CSV file while creating table in databricks. Upload error ! unable to processing file.csv [object object]
Unable to load CSV file while creating table in databricks. Upload error ! unable to processing file.csv [object object]
I am using community edition
I want to create table using CSV
Need solution for this
Need solution for this

Hi @subash Shan Are you using ADLS OR DBFS?

Where is the csv file? What is your code?

As mentioned you want to create table using CSV.
For example I have tried the below approach using ADLS and using databricks dbfs.
,
If you have your file in the dbfs location you can try the below approach to read the file from the dbfs
df_read = spark.read.csv("/FileStore/tables/delta/sample/sample.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

Read the sample CSV file for diamonds into a Spark DataFrame
The below data used from the databricks provided datasets
diamonds_df = spark.read \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .load("/databricks-datasets/Rdatasets/data-001/csv/ggplot2/diamonds.csv")
display(diamonds_df)

_c0 carat   cut color   clarity depth   table   price   x   y   z
1   0.23    Ideal   E   SI2 61.5    55  326 3.95    3.98    2.43
2   0.21    Premium E   SI1 59.8    61  326 3.89    3.84    2.31
3   0.23    Good    E   VS1 56.9    65  327 4.05    4.07    2.31
4   0.29    Premium I   VS2 62.4    58  334 4.2 4.23    2.63
5   0.31    Good    J   SI2 63.3    58  335 4.34    4.35    2.75


Creating delta table in databricks using the saveAsTable method.
diamonds_df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("diamonds_table")

Results:
_c0 carat   cut color   clarity depth   table   price   x   y   z
1   0.23    Ideal   E   SI2 61.5    55  326 3.95    3.98    2.43
2   0.21    Premium E   SI1 59.8    61  326 3.89    3.84    2.31
3   0.23    Good    E   VS1 56.9    65  327 4.05    4.07    2.31
4   0.29    Premium I   VS2 62.4    58  334 4.2 4.23    2.63
5   0.31    Good    J   SI2 63.3    58  335 4.34    4.35    2.75


Next, I have tried using the ADLS I have a file called taxi_zone.csv in ADLS
Setting up connection for ADLS and Databricks
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<YOUR STORAGE ACCOUNT NAME>.dfs.core.windows.net","< STORAGE ACCOUNT ACCESS KEY>")

Reading the File from path as below:
csv_file_path =  f"abfss://ws-container@dileepsynapsestg.dfs.core.windows.net/nyc_green_taxi_data/raw/taxi_zone.csv"
df = spark.read.csv(csv_file_path, header=True, inferSchema=True)
df.show()

+----------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
|LocationID|      Borough|                Zone|service_zone|
+----------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
|         1|          EWR|      Newark Airport|         EWR|
|         2|       Queens|         Jamaica Bay|   Boro Zone|
|         3|        Bronx|Allerton/Pelham G...|   Boro Zone|
|         4|    Manhattan|       Alphabet City| Yellow Zone|
|         5|Staten Island|       Arden Heights|   Boro Zone|
------------------------------------------------------------

Writing the table to databricks using the saveAsTable  method.
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("taxi_zone_delta_table")

Results:
%sql
Select  *  from taxi_zone_delta_table

+----------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
|LocationID|      Borough|                Zone|service_zone|
+----------+-------------+--------------------+------------+
|         1|          EWR|      Newark Airport|         EWR|
|         2|       Queens|         Jamaica Bay|   Boro Zone|
|         3|        Bronx|Allerton/Pelham G...|   Boro Zone|
|         4|    Manhattan|       Alphabet City| Yellow Zone|
|         5|Staten Island|       Arden Heights|   Boro Zone|
------------------------------------------------------------


